# Symfony not Render CollectionType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I create a form for a collection type of data in a separated from my controller

its my controller

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 * @Route("/phonebook/add", name="add")
 */
public function addPerson()
{
$person = new PhoneBookP();
$form = $this->createForm(PersoanlBookType::class, $person);

return $this->render(
    'default/add.html.twig',
    array('form' => $form->createView())
);
}
```

and its my form

```
->add('emails', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => EmailType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'attr'         => [
                    'class' => "emails-collection",
                ],
            ))
```

and my twig is

```
{% block body %}
{{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

it has no error and work in any common field (like NumberType,..) but not render CollectionType in my output. I using Symfony 4. whats my wrong?

Comment: Can you show your `controller`?

Comment: yes, i edit the question

Comment: May be `PersoanlBookType` to `PersonalBookType`?

Comment: Can You show your twig `default/add.html.twig`?

Comment: Did you resolve your problems?

Comment: still not. but i create jquery btn and function to add form input manualy. im not sure this true

Answer (score 1):

in your rendering form you need to do this:

```
$person = new PhoneBookP();
//addEmail() is the arraycollection in your PhoneBookP Entity
//to be able to load the form, you need to add one from your arraycollection
$person->addEmail(new Email());
$form = $this->createForm(PersoanlBookType::class, $person);
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags `form_start` and `form_end` only render the `<form>`-tags. To render the rest of the form elements call the `form`-twig-helper inside the `<form>`-tags too:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
   {{form(form)}}
    <button type="submit">Register!</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```